# Is it possible to use Obsolete attribute on only a getter or a setter of a property

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use Obsolete attribute on only a getter or a setter of a property?

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
public int Id {
    get { return _id;}
    [Obsolete("Going forward, this property is readonly",true)]
    set { _id = value;}
}
```

but obviously that will not build. Is there a work around that allows me to apply this attribute to just the setter?

Comment: Since you have it set to raise errors, why not just remove the setter, they'll be notified it's read only.

Comment: You can still disable the error using the `#pragma warning` directive, even though it's not just a warning. That way the legacy code will still build, while future code won't.

Answer (score 15):

I think that this can't be done because, for some reason, it has been specifically disallowed for the Obsolete attribute.  According to the rules defined around attribute targets, there doesn't appear to be any reason that the Obsolete attribute would not be valid on a property get or set accessor.  In order to apply an attribute to a property set accessor, [that attribute must be applicable to either a method, parameter, or return value target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0%28VS.80%29.aspx).  If you look at [the Obsolete attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx), you can see that "method" is one of the valid targets for that attribute.

In fact, you can define your own attribute with the same valid targets as the Obsolete attribute [with the AttributeUsage attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw5zxet9%28VS.71%29.aspx), and you'll find that you can apply it to a property get or set accessor whereas you cannot apply the Obsolete attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
class MyMethodAttribute : Attribute { }

class MyClass
{
    private int _Id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }

        [MyMethodAttribute] // this works because "Method" is a valid target for this attribute
        [Obsolete] // this does not work, even though "Method" is a valid target for the Obsolete attribute
        set { _Id = value; }
    }
}
```

If you try creating your own attribute that is not valid on a property set accessor and you apply it there, then you may notice the error message is slightly different.  The error message for your custom attribute will be "Attribute 'YourCustomAttribute' is not valid on this declaration type.", whereas the error message for the Obsolete attribute is "Attribute 'Obsolete' is not valid on property or event accessors."  The fact that the error message is different makes me believe that this is a rule that is, for whatever reason, explicitly built into the compiler for the Obsolete attribute, rather than relying on the AttributeUsage attribute that is, supposedly, applied to the Obsolete attribute.

Comment: @Shimmy I wasn't suggesting to derive a class from `ObsoleteAttribute`, but was just explaining the observations that lead me to believe that this restriction on the usage of the Obsolete attribute is determined by the implementation of the compiler, not .NET attribute usage rules. I'm not sure why the fact that the class is sealed matters.

Comment: @Dr.Willy, I missed it sorry... I have a property I need it to be read-write, but don't want the write to be used, I only need to fulfill a contract requirement, the `ObsoleteAttribute` could be handy here.

Comment: @Shimmy When you say "contract requirement", do you mean a .NET interface? If so, then I suggest using the "Implement Interface Explicitly" option and the providing an alternate getter-only property on your class with the same name. That way, the setter is not easily available to a developer who is using your class. However, keep in mind that it would still be very possible for that property to be accessed; any code treating that object as its interface can access it. Therefore, still implement the getter, and for the setter probably either implement it or throw a NotSupportedException.

Comment: @Dr.Willy, I have a code-first property `FullName` that returns the combination of `FirstName` and `LastName`, and I want it to be written to the database for indexing and searching purposes. ITOH I don't want it to be settable by humans (as opposed to EF etc.).

Answer (score 14):

The ability to do this has now been included in C# 8.0.

Thank you to Dr. Wily's Apprentice who pointed out this was inconsistent to other attributes in his answer, and inspired me to implement this.

The PR where these changes were made is here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/32571

Comment: Out of curiosity: Any chance for a link to see your changes? (assuming they are in a public GitHub repository)

Comment: @UweKeim. added to the answer