# Access a hidden property from static method

Tags: c#

Given the following

```
class BaseClass
{
    public int Property {get; protected set;}
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new int Property {get; set;} //Hides BaseClass.Property

    public static DerivedClass Build()
    {
         var result = new DerivedClass
         {
              Property = 17;
              //base.Property = 17; // this doesn't compile
         }
         //((BaseClass)result).Property = 17; // this doesn't compile
    }
}
```

Is there any way to set BaseClass.Property from a static method inside the DerivedClass.

Reflection or Unsafe code is not what I want! I want a non hacky way of setting something which we do legally have access to, but I just can't work out how to set.

Comment: You shouldn't be hiding properties like this in the first place.  If you have a different property, give it a different name, if it represents the same conceptual property, just use the base class's property.

Comment: The answer is no, you should rethink the problem

Comment: A public property having a protected set and get? Honestly? Does this even compile?

Comment: Why do you want to *hide* the property in the first place, when you want to access the original one? This sounds like a really bad idea. Why do you want this? What´s your **actual** problem?

Comment: There ***is*** a way to access the base class's `Property` value, but it needs to not be hidden.  If `DerivedClass` didn't hide the `Property` value, then you'd be able to do `result.Property = 17;`.

Comment: The reason this is being done, is because I'm refactoring some legacy code. The class should be immutable, but it's mutated all over the place, so I'm extracting a base class with protected setter, and hiding the properties so they can set the base properties publicly.

Comment: Why did you remove the `protected` keyword from the getter?  That basically invalidates the answers above.

Comment: Because it was a mistake, and as HimBromBeere pointed out, it probably wouldn't compile

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Favor composition over inheritance.  If you want to make an immutable version of to a mutable type, create a type type that composes it, rather than a derived type that attempts to hide the members.  Same same if you're trying to make an immutable type mutable.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Also, if your class is mutated all over the place, the type is not in fact "immutable".

Comment: The problem is the code base is over a million LOC, and performance critical. This class is used all over the place, and should really just be an immutable POCO As such an interface isn't practical, as it will significantly slow down performance, so wrapping the class wouldn't work.

Comment: @Servy: Conceptually it should be immutable. Alas, earlier developers were cowboys of a sort...

Comment: You can't fix a fundamentally wrong design. Redesign.

Comment: @PatrickHofman
I wish I could Redesign. unfortunately, we can't afford 6 months to rebuild our product from scratch. I know this is ugly. I know this is a hack. but we're stuck with it, and I'm trying to make the best of it I can.

Comment: So why not try to fix this and just live with the broken design? It feels to me you are breaking more than you can fix.

Comment: Maybe you could just make the proerties setter obsolete? I know this doesn´t work directly, however there are ways to achieve something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108300/is-it-possible-to-use-obsolete-attribute-on-only-a-getter-or-a-setter-of-a-prope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to access an overridden property from a static method of the class:

1. Add to the class a new property that accesses the base property:

   ```
   private double BaseProperty { get => base.MyProperty; set => base.MyProperty = value; }
   ```
2. Use that new property from your static:

   ```
   var result = new DerivedClass
   {
       BaseProperty = 17;
   }
   ```

---

Here is a situation where the above technique is the cleanest solution I have found.
Consider XAML that refers to a BindableProperty, in a class library.
(In my case, the class library is Xamarin Forms.)

*Without changing the property name,* I want to decouple the base property (used by code compiled into the library) from the XAML-visible property (in my subclass).
The specific use is making text auto-fit, which X-Forms doesn't yet support.

The detail that is relevant here, is that I have the following BindableProperty declaration:

```
public new static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create("FontSize", typeof(double), typeof(AutofitLabel), -1.0,
        propertyChanged: (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue) => {
            ((AutofitLabel)bindable).BaseFontSize = (double)newValue;
        });
```

which uses this private property:

```
private double BaseFontSize { get => base.FontSize; set => base.FontSize = value; }
```

What this accomplishes, is to initially set base.FontSize - which will be used by layout logic inside library's `Label` or other text-containing view - to the value set in XAML. Elsewhere in my subclass, I have logic that lowers base.FontSize as needed, once the available width/height are known.

This approach makes it possible to use the library without altering its source code, yet make it appear, to clients of my subclass, that auto-fitting is built-in.
It wouldn't be valid to change `FontSize` that is visible to client code - that represents the *requested* size.  [However, that *is* the approach taken by Charles Petzold in XF Book Ch. 5 "EmpiricalFontSizePage"](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/blob/master/Chapter05/EmpiricalFontSize/EmpiricalFontSize/EmpiricalFontSize/EmpiricalFontSizePage.cs). Also, Petzold has the page itself deal with the auto-sizing - which is not convenient.

The challenge is the need to tell the library what actual `FontSize` to use.
Ergo this solution.

All other approaches I've found online require complex custom renderers, replicating logic already existing in XF library.

Comment: Brilliant. Someone that actually listens to the OP and tries to help them out.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to set BaseClass.Property from a static method inside the DerivedClass.

Yes, rethink your design. It is flawed. Hiding a property and then wanting to set the exact same value on the base and derived class? There seems something really wrong.

You don't necessarily need to hide the property, you could override it, but then it wouldn't make too much sense. It seems the only objective you have is to have different access modifiers on your base class and derived class. This goes against OOP rules, and should be avoided.

Comment: Alas, I am driven to this by refactoring some legacy class. The class should be immutable, but it's mutated all over the place, so I'm extracting a base class with protected setter, and hiding the properties so they can set the base properties publicly.

Comment: But why the protected setter on the base class and then being able to set it from the derived class? If you want to declare it in the base class, make it a protected field, so the deriving classes can determine how they want to expose the field.

Answer (score 1):

If you can introduce another *intermediate* class, then you can obviously do this. But as others have said, it doesn't just have a code *smell*, it's positively poisonous.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public int Property { get; protected set; }
}

class InterClass : BaseClass
{
    protected void DoFunnyStuff(int value)
    {
        this.Property = value;
    }
}

class DerivedClass : InterClass
{
    public new int Property { get; set; } //Hides BaseClass.Property

    public static DerivedClass Build()
    {
        DerivedClass result = new DerivedClass
        {
            Property = 17
            //base.Property = 17; // this doesn't compile
        };
        result.DoFunnyStuff(17);
        return result;
        //((BaseClass)result).Property = 17; // this doesn't compile
    }
}
```

So `DerivedClass` does inherit from `BaseClass` still, but not directly. You can apply various tricks to try to minimize how much other code is exposed to the existence of `InterClass`.

Comment: I agree it's horrible, and I've managed to find a way round it. However as the only answer which actually answered the question, I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to modify the APIs behaviour in such a way that something which was mutable before should not be mutable any more. So why not defining a new property, which is really immutable and make the existing one `Obsolete` instead o trying to hide the original property but not hiding it?

```
class LegacyClass
{
    [Obsolete("Use NewMember instead")]
    public string ExistingMember { get; set; } // should actually be immutable
    public string NewMember { get { ... } }
}
```

This way you don´t break existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible through reflection: [Property hiding and reflection (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715023/property-hiding-and-reflection-c)

No it's not possible in other ways, if you hide a property by design it's because you don't want give access to that from DerivedClass

Reflection allows you to access for particular purpose, it's not an hacky way the use of reflection.

It's an hacky way to access to a property that you have hidden by design.

If you want access in a legal way to a property you should not hide it.